# dynamoDB - what is better, 2 queries or 1 scan?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

what is the better way to get data from dynamoDB (assuming that the table is huge)
in the following scenario:

[OPTION1 - 1 scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4riOh.png)

1. get all items, filter by userID in canAccess (I am afraid that the scan will be time consuming)

| partitionkey | sortkey | attribute1 | attribute2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mainId1 | subId1#meta | **canAccess** | **info** |
|  |  | set[uesrId1,uesrId2] | string |
| mainId1 | subId2#meta | **canAccess** | **info** |
|  |  | set[uesrId1] | string |

[OPTION2 - 2 queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC5OC.png)

1. res = query GSI: get all canAccess==userId
2. batch query: get all data by pk in res[pk] filter by start with [extracted subid].

*2.(alternative)  get all data by pk,sk in res[pk,sk]

| partitionkey | sortkey | attribute1 | attribute2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mainId1 | subId1# meta | **info** | ... |
|  |  | string | ... |
| mainId1 | subId1# uesrId1 | **canAccess-GSI** | ... |
|  |  | uesrId1 | ... |
| mainId1 | subId1# uesrId2 | **canAccess-GSI** | ... |
|  |  | uesrId2 | ... |
| mainId1 | subId2# meta | **info** | ... |
|  |  | string | ... |
| mainId1 | subId2# uesrId1 | **canAccess-GSI** | ... |
|  |  | uesrId1 | ... |

Comment: If you can identify the items in advance using keys, then you should query.

Comment: at the 2nd option by making a preparation query I can I identify the items, but I have to do 2 queries instead of 1 scan. so which way is better? @jarmod

Comment: There is no scenario that I can think of with a 'huge' table where scan is going to be preferable to a small number of queries.